# How to close the ports opened through "http-server"programatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to host HTML pages using http-server. Once I run the command to host the pages in consecutive http-servers, stop the command and run it again, I get the following Error:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:5501
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1290:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1338:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1469:7)
    at internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:47:5)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:763:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:303:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:872:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1317:8)
    at internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:872:3)
```

I tried searching ways to close these ports through program. But I could not find any suitable solution

The below code is trying host every folder present inside the hosted folder in consecutive ports hosted by http-server.

runScripts.js file:

```
function runServer() {
  hostedFolder = '../hosted';
  nfiles = []
  fs.readdirSync(hostedFolder).forEach(file => {
    nfiles.push(file);
  })
  for (j = 0; j < nfiles.length; j++) {
    server = "http-server ../hosted/" + nfiles[j] + "  -p 550" + j
    console.log("Hosted server",server)
    runMultipleCommandWithWait2(server)
  }
}

function runMultipleCommandWithWait2(server) {
  console.log("Starting the server now...")

  Promise.coroutine(function* () {
    var commands = [server];
    for (var i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
      yield cmd.run(commands[i]);
    }
  })();
}
```

I want a way to kill these ports programatically so that I can continuously and consecutively host the folders without any error.

Comment: a port can only be open if a program has it open - clearly you're not stopping the program that has the port open

Comment: by the way, `"  -p 550" + j` will use ports 5500 ... 5509, then 55010 to 55099, then 550100 - which would be invalid ... so, a) your ports are only "consecutive" for the first 10, and then the next 90; and b) if you have 101 folders, you'll get a failure

Comment: What is `cmd.run`? Is it some kind of library function? Which library are you using?

Comment: the odd thing is that the error refers to the second server you're starting, `0.0.0.0:5501` wonder why that port is still open, yet the first isn't

Comment: also ... `var commands = [server];
    for (var i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
      yield cmd.run(commands[i]);
    }` ... isn't that just an oddly long winded way of just doing `yield cmd.run(server)` - since `commands` is an array, of length 1, with the only element having the value `server`

Comment: @JaromandaX I would guess that `cmd.run()` is launching separate processes, one for each port. The OP is killing the "original" process (`5500`) but not killing all the processes spawned from it (those listening on `5501` onwards).